# Click this OR that, then do something

Tags: jquery, selector

I suppose the title is quite self-explanatory.

I want to close a div when a user clicks on an overlay OR on a link. I know you can just write two functions like so:

```
$("#close-search").click(function() {
    $("#branding #searchform").fadeOut("fast");
    $("#global-overlay").fadeOut("fast");
});

$("#global-overlay").click(function() {
    $(this).fadeOut("fast");
    $("#branding #searchform").fadeOut("fast");
});
```

Or you can write one function, like so:

```
function closeSearch {
    $(this).fadeOut("fast");
    $("#branding #searchform").fadeOut("fast");
}

$("#close-search").click(function() {
    closeSearch();
});

$("#global-overlay").click(function() {
    closeSearch();
});
```

I tried this, but it didn't work.

```
$("#close-search", "#global-overlay").click(function() {
        $("#branding #searchform").fadeOut("fast");
        $("#global-overlay").fadeOut("fast");
    });
```

But is it possible to write this in one line? (Something like `$("#close-search" OR #global-overlay")`)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

comma seperated means this or that

```
$("#close-search, #global-overlay")
```

Multiple [selector](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/)

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
$("#close-search, #global-overlay").click(function() {
      $("#branding #searchform").fadeOut("fast");
      $("#global-overlay").fadeOut("fast");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Untested:

Try this:

```
$("#close-search, #global-overlay").click(function() {
        $("#branding #searchform").fadeOut("fast");
        $("#global-overlay").fadeOut("fast");
    });
```

notice the string in the selector isn't split like an array, instead - the Sizzle selector will do this for you.